# how to DIFF all commits returned by git log --grep='1234567'? How to see all changes made in the source code for some task?

Tags: git, git-diff

I use commit messages like '#1111 some name' where #1111 is task id.

so to find all commits related to that task I use

```
git log --grep='1111'
```

but if I need to see ALL changes for the whole task, I should execute **git show** for each commit. It is not convenient since commits change each other.

During the implementation, those commits are in the separate branch so I can easily compare it to origin/master.
But after the merge, I lose such ability.

So the question:

How to see a diff of all commits that are listed by **git log --grep='1111'** ?

How to see all changes made in the source code for some task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git log` can show the diff for every commit with an option `-p/--patch`:

```
git log --grep='1111' -p
```